# npm install with my code changes in a specific library

Tags: angular, node-modules

I am using the vis.js library to build a timeline but i have an error that i only fix if i made some changes in the library. So, the problem is when i am doing npm install in another computer i get the last version of vis.js and not my version.
Is there any way to fix this problem? I need create a library for me and change the package.json or there is other way to do that?
I am trying fix this error without change the library but is being hard because i can't have access the variables of the library. When you made some event the variables updated in real time and i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Initially if you want to install a specific version of a package and add it to the package.json file you would use `npm install <package>@<version>`. But you can also remove any symbols from the package version within package.json to use a specific version too and then just run `npm i`.

```
"depedencies": {
 "vis-js": "1.0.0"
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: if i do any change i don't need put my changes in a repository? So, when i run the command npm install he need something where get the new files right?

Comment: Typically you just push package.json into your repo but leave node_modules out. Every time another person pulls a changed package.json then all they would need to do is just run ```npm install``` to have the same dependencies as you.

Comment: right, but for example the version that i have is "vis": "^4.21.0-EOL" and if i change this version to this example "vis": "^4.22". I don't need put a link in anywhere to get the new files when you run the command npm install. I don't know if I am being clear

Comment: No, you don't need to put in a link or login as long as the package is public.